# Downloading dev-full

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo4w

I have downloaded OSGeo4W 64-bit from https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html and would like to do a 'bleeding edge development build" on my Windows 10. So I select clicked Run and selected Advanced Install, install from internet, set root directory, direct connection, chose the download site, then it gets to the Select Packages stage.

I click Next and immediately get an Installation Status that says "OSGeo4W installation completed successfully" at the top and "Nothing needed to be installed" at the bottom with the Finish button. I have looked around and QGIS isn't installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you select the version (not defaulted to skip) see https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdIQ7.png for an example - please note there are a lot of changes on https://www.qgis.org/en/site/index.html as qgis 3.0 is rolling out on different OS's this weekend (23rd Feb 2018)

Comment: You didn't select any packages, you just clicked Next.

Comment: Just clicking `Next` would have worked if you had a previous version already installed.